# Why Sqlite always keeps left hand side records in a LEFT JOIN

Tags: postgresql, sqlite, left-join

I have the following table with the given data in it:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
(
   id               INT,
   data             TEXT
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (1, 'hello');
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (2, 'hello');
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (3, 'hello');
```

When doing a LEFT JOIN on it self with the following query

```
SELECT * FROM my_table t1
LEFT JOIN my_table t2 ON t1.data = t2.data;
```

we get, as expected, the following result

```
1,hello,1,hello
1,hello,2,hello
1,hello,3,hello
2,hello,1,hello
2,hello,2,hello
2,hello,3,hello
3,hello,1,hello
3,hello,2,hello
3,hello,3,hello
```

What I don't understand clearly is when I put another joining condition that should evict all records we still get 3 records

```
SELECT * from my_table t1
  LEFT JOIN my_table t2 ON t1.data = t2.data AND t1.data = 'goodbye';

1,hello,<null>,<null>
2,hello,<null>,<null>
3,hello,<null>,<null>
```

However when the same condition is put on the WHERE clause then all records are filtered out

```
SELECT * FROM my_table t1
  LEFT JOIN my_table t2 ON t1.data = t2.data
WHERE t1.data = 'goodbye';
```

It looks like the records on the left hand side of the join cannot be removed in any way by the filters on the ON clause although they could be. Is it because we are doing a LEFT JOIN and therefore Sqlite keeps all the records on the left hand side ignoring whatever condition on the ON that could remove them?

Comment: Oracle and SQL Server behave the same as Postgres (and this is what I would expect - just like you). So this seems a bug in SQLite

Comment: Even the [tag:left-join] tag you linked explains why this happens (BTW it's the same in PostgreSQL too).

Comment: Just double-checked: [Postgres too works that way](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/52b07/1)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name are you sure in Oracle and SQL Server? That would be a pretty huge violation of the SQL spec.

Comment: @pozs is right. This is an expected behavior. Oracle, MSSQL, PostgreSQL and SQLight will all work correctly in this case.

Comment: After second reading: what you want to achieve is the `INNER JOIN`; and your query with `WHERE` works because it makes OUTER JOINs to turn into INNER ones (because it usually manually eliminates NULLs -- or in your case: rows in the original/left table).

Comment: @pozs you are completely right, postgres does behave the same. I must have gotten confused when I tried it out on it. I will correct this in the description.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of a LEFT OUTER JOIN is to preserve unmatched rows from the left-hand side. That's what you see here.

```
SELECT * from my_table t1
  LEFT JOIN my_table t2 ON t1.data = t2.data AND t1.data = 'goodbye';

1,hello,null,null
2,hello,null,null
3,hello,null,null
```

The first two columns are the unmatched rows from the left-hand side (t1). The second two columns are joined rows with null in the columns of the right-hand side (t2).

You can eliminate all the rows by changing from a LEFT OUTER JOIN to an INNER JOIN. I don't know what you're trying to accomplish, so I don't know whether that's a good idea in your case.

Comment: I understand that as you said the point of a LEFT OUTER JOIN is to preserve the row on the left side. What was new, and surprising to me was that even though a condition on the ON clause would filter out rows from the left side they remained.

Comment: I actually was not trying to accomplish something, it is more that we stumble upon this behavior that we didn't know about and would cause some test failures. Now it is clear that it is an expected behavior and that most (if not all) db engines behave the same (according to what has been reported by other people in their comments).

Comment: LEFT JOIN has been part of SQL standards since 1992 (SQL-92). Its behavior hasn't changed. About the person writing the failing tests, you need to ask "What else does he not know?"